# Inno Setup : Exclude all files with extension

Tags: inno-setup

I want to exclude all files with a specific extension - ".ecw". I use the following script, but it does nothing:

```
[Files]
Source: "*"; Excludes: .ecw; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags:ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "*"; Excludes: "*.ecw"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

[image]

Comment: Show us an output of Inno Setup compiler.

Comment: It compiles ok and setup package generated. I will add screenshot to my question.

Comment: There's no `Excludes: "*.ecw"` in the entry that selects the `..\ZP\biv\x64\Debug\*` files.

Comment: You mean the previous rule is cancelled by the next one?

Comment: The previous rule selects file in the current working directory (with exception of .ecw files). The second rule select all files in `..\ZP\biv\x64\Debug\*`. They do not cancel each other, they both work separately. Maybe you actually do not even want the `Source: "*"` rule.

Comment: Now it works, thank you!

Comment: How about showing us your working code?

Answer (score 9):

Here is working script:

```
Source: "..\ZP\bin\x64\Debug\*"; Excludes: "*.BIN,*.pdb,*.ecw"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

Adding Excludes: "...bla bla..."; parameter for every path where you need to exclude specific extensions made it work.